# How would I listen for gestures across the users entire device with an AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, android-service, accessibility

How would I listen for gestures across the users entire device with an AccessibilityService in android?
My current idea its to use a GestureResultCallback() method but I don't know how to register that method in my service.

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible with an `AccessibilityService`.

Comment: Do you know what it's possible with?

Comment: AFAIK, what you want cannot be accomplished by a regular app. A custom Android build could, and possibly an app on a rooted device could.